# Running selenium tests with Jenkins on another server

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins

I'm using TestNG, Maven and Jenkins to run my code(Java).
I need run my tests on another server so what I tried so far is running Jenkins on the server as a service and schedule the jobs but it created a problem that the tests were running in the background (causing all tests to fail), I tried configuring the Jenkins service as in this picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uDSU.png)

But it didn't work, so I tried to run Jenkins not as a service, the tests ran perfectly but I wasn't able to schedule jobs because Jenkins couldn't run 24/7 on this server because it wasn't a service.

Is there any way to run jenkins 24/7 on a server without making it a service?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have multiple jenkins servers the scheduled selenium jobs with multiple selenium grids.

I'm not sure what you mean that it can't run 24/7 because it isn't a service.

I am not using it as a service and I launch it from a .bat script with the contents as this:

```
@title Jenkins
@java -jar C:\Jenkins\jenkins.war
```

This opens it in a console window and will run until the window is either closed manually or the computer is restarted.

I set my servers to auto login through the registry and added the .bat scripts to the startup folder so that they are launched upon login.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that